# Why does a C++ header file not need to include the implementing file (.cpp)?

Tags: c++, header

Why does a C++ header file not need to include the implementing file (.cpp)?

I'm wondering if the debugger does the job or does it just not need it?

Comment: Because the .cpp file includes the .h file. Not a real question.

Comment: It is done by the [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, it isn't 'done by the compiler and the linker'. It isn't done at all.

Comment: Because C++ isn't Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .cpp file includes the header, not the other way around

Your question has been answered here:

[Why don't I need to include library.cpp in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955532/why-dont-i-need-to-include-library-cpp-in-the-header)

Good luck

Comment: o(>﹏<)o Sorry,I got entropy added in universe again

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just needs the header file to comply to the interfaces.

To run and execute the code, you need the implementation, but not in source, but as a library. It might be dynamic (.so - file on linux, .dll on Windows) or it gets statically linked after compilation.

For debugging, you need the source file to step through the lines.

Answer (score 0):

A header file is primarily just type declarations and references to code that is implemented in other files.  Source files need to know those declarations, but the header files do not need to know the implementations (except for inlines).  Multiple source files can use the same header file, and the linker will make sure they get access to the shared implementation code as needed.